# MongoDB insertMany BulkWriteError, avoid catch if duplicate key and perform then function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm importing multiple items in DB calling with a cron job the following function:

```
async function importItems(items){
return item_schema.insertMany(items, {ordered: false})
    .then(docs => {
        const n = docs ? docs.length : 0
        docs.map((item) => {
            /* Do something */
        })
        return `New items imported ${n} / ${items.length}`
    })
    .catch(error(500, `Error importing items.`))
}
```

Since a few of items could be previously imported, I'm getting the *BulkWriteError* due to duplicate key (*'item_id'*) that always trigger *catch*.

My problem is that I need to "do something" with the n new items successfully imported that I get in the *docs* array in *then* function, ignoring the *catch*.

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: If I understand you currently you are trying to insert only the items that aren’t previously imported **or** you are trying to insert and if some already exists update

Comment: I'm trying to insert only the items that aren’t previously imported.
I try to insert everything, if already exist I have to ignore it, if new I have to do something after inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function importItems(items) {
    return item_schema.find({
            item_id: {
                $in: items.map((item) => item.item_id) // Check if item_id is one of the array values
            }
        })
        .then((documents) => {
            // documents is all the items that already exists
            const newItems = items.filter((item) => !documents.find((doc) => doc.item_id === item.item_id));
            return item_schema.insertMany(newItems, { ordered: false })
                .then((docs) => {
                    const n = docs ? docs.length : 0
                    docs.map((item) => {
                        /* Do something */
                    })
                    return `New items imported ${n} / ${items.length}`
                })
                .catch(error(500, `Error importing items.`));
        })
        .catch(error(500, `Error importing items.`));
}
```